# Block/Proc Returning Array within an Array Explanation

Tags: ruby

The prompt: 
Extend the Array class to include a method named `my_each` that takes a block, calls the block on every element of the array, and then returns the original array.

```
class Array
  def my_each(&prc)
    if block_given?
      proc.call(self)
    else
      for i in (0..self.length-1)
        puts self[i]
      end
    end
    self
  end
end
```

This is what I put together and I don't have a good understanding of how Blocks/Procs work within this context, but somehow I magically wrote the code that passed 3 of the 4 RSPEC tests.

```
  describe "#my_each" do
    it "calls the block passed to it" do
      expect do |block|
        ["test array"].my_each(&block)
      end.to yield_control.once
    end

    it "yields each element to the block" do
      expect do |block|
        ["el1", "el2"].my_each(&block)
      end.to yield_successive_args("el1", "el2")
    end

    it "does NOT call the built-in #each method" do
      original_array = ["original array"]
      expect(original_array).not_to receive(:each)
      original_array.my_each {}
    end

    it "is chainable and returns the original array" do
      original_array = ["original array"]
      expect(original_array.my_each {}).to eq(original_array)
    end
  end
```

All of the above RSPEC tests passes with the exception of the second one, where my code returns [["el1", "el2"]] when ["el1", "el2"] is expected. Can someone please give me an explanation of how or why I am receiving a nested array here?

Can someone also give me an explanation of how the code is running as a block is passing through this method? I'm not sure if my "else" condition is actually even necessary in the context of the RSPEC tests. I'm generally confused by the concept of passing blocks through self-written methods and how they interact with the method itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you paste rspec output with the failure message?

Comment: 1) Array#my_each yields each element to the block
     Failure/Error: expect do |block|
       expected given block to yield successively with arguments, but yielded with unexpected arguments
       expected: ["el1", "el2"]
            got: [["el1", "el2"]]
     # ./spec/03_iteration_spec.rb:106:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Not sure how to do the formatting for comments : /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first part of your condition, you pass the whole array to the block:

```
if block_given?
  proc.call(self)
else
# ...
```

E.g. for an array of `["el1", "el2"]` you do `proc.call(["el1", "el2"])`. What you expect in the test are two consecutive calls:

```
proc.call("el1")
proc.call("el2")
```

To do that you need to use a loop also in the first part of the condition and pass there an array element, not the whole array:

```
if block_given?
  for i in (0..self.length-1)
     proc.call(self[i])
  end
else
  for i in (0..self.length-1)
    puts self[i]
  end
end
```

Comment: Damn, the way you explained it makes perfect sense. I guess it's just a matter of wrapping my mind around using procs in that fashion.. just weird for me to conceptualize since it adds a new dimension to it. I still don't really understand what the benefit of using blocks/procs are but I'm sure I'll get there. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
  proc.call(self)
```

is the culprit. `self` is the whole array.

Extend the Array class to include a method named my_each

```
class Array
  def my_each
  end
end
```

that takes a block,

```
#every method in ruby accepts a block, it is just ignored when not used (yielded to). Do nothing.
```

calls the block on every element of the array,

```
class Array
  def my_each
    for element in self
      yield element
    end
  end
end
```

and then returns the original array.

```
# "for" loops do this. Do nothing. It should pass.
```

Comment: `for` is simply syntactic sugar for `each`. This sounds like an assignment to *re-implement* `each`, not simply wrap it. Otherwise, you could even more simply write `def my_each(&blk) each(&blk) end` or even just `alias_method :my_each, :each`

Comment: Yeah, Jörg is right, this exercise was meant to re-implement a carbon copy of the "each" method. Sorry if that was unclear! Jörg can you explain what you mean when you say "wrapping it"? One of our expectations for this exercise was not to use the "each" method in creating this (RSPEC #3), is that what you had (not) meant by that?